# Updating for Tableau Monthly Runs

Tags: excel, tableau-api, dashboard

I have a Tableau dashboard file that I need to run on a monthly basis for data that is rolling twelve months.

The data is housed in an Excel worksheet. When I created the Tableau dashboard, I did not use a Custom SQL Query but rather imported the entire sheet.

The problem I am running into is the following - last month, the Excel sheet contained data starting from January 2017 to December 2017. However, this month's iteration contains data from February 2017 to January 2018 since the file is a rolling twelve months. Since Tableau can no longer find data for January 2017, it keeps giving me an error when I am trying to update the dashboard. I should add that I am only using the Total and Average columns in the file so I don't actually need the individual month columns.

Any ideas how to fix this other than recreating the entire dashboard using custom SQL?

Comment: "I hope this is an easy fix" and "thank you" are unnecessary banter. It's nice to be polite, but this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. In the future, keep your questions clear, concise, and professional. And you can banter as you wish in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: does the excel sheet has data for jan 2017?

Comment: You say an error is being thrown when you try to update the dashboard--what does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your data source to a Tableau Extract by going to **Data Source**, **Edit Data Source**, **Extract**. Then you can select **Extract**, **Append Data from File...** and add the data from January.

[image: Screenshot from Data Extract menu]